# How to check metadata stored in FBX files?

Tags: unity, data, fbx

Is there a way to check and edit metadata information stored in FBX files? I'm using 3ds Max's fbx exporter. Can this be done with it or is there any other tool for that?

For example: adding name, contact info, tags or anything that provides ownership of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to do but you can always export it from 3ds max in ascii format instead of binary and open it later in a text editor (notepad).